# iOS Convert m4a to amr before uploading

Tags: ios, core-audio, amr

I'm working on an app which could record your voice and then mix with background music. I use `AVAssetExportSession` to mix and export to .m4a format which is OK, but the size is too large.

So here is my question:

1. Is there any simple way to mix two audios in amr format which is small enough?
2. If not how can I convert .m4a to amr?

Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like you have some research to do on your end. These questions are relatively broad, and I think you'll have success working on it on your own. If you have a specific question or trouble implementing them, we are happy to help.

Comment: Hi sschale, thanks for your reply. I found `opencore-amr-iOS` in GitHub and I'll try it now.